# How can I make this fading divider responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have a divider element styled with the following CSS properties:

```css
.divider {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#000), to(#fff));
}
```

So I have 2 questions, how can I make this fading effect responsive? The fading starts at a fixed length by now.

And can somebody explain/link me an explanation to the

```css
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#000), to(#fff));
```

I found it online as what I need but I don't quiet understand what each of those numbers is for, the last one is the size but % doesn't work here sadly, the other numbers don't really change anything if I change them.

Comment: First of all, please do not show us mere snippets of CSS, that lack any sensible context - provide a proper [mre] of your issue. _"how can I make this fading effect responsive?"_ - clarify in _what way_ you want it to be responsive.

Comment: _"And can somebody explain/link me an explanation"_ - search engines are available on the internet, so please show a bit of initial effort, instead of asking to be spoon-fed.

Comment: @CBroe Well I used that class on a div to seperate 2 elements, so to reproduce it youd need a div and give it that class. 
About the search engine, uhh yeah i tried that but with no success thats why I asked on a forum.

Comment: _"so to reproduce it youd need [...]"_ - then provide that in your question, please. It makes much more sense that _you_ invest that effort once, instead of expecting everyone here who wants to look into your problem to create a working example on their own.

Comment: You are right, I will remember that for the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new gradient syntax:

```css
.divider {
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, black 50%, white 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
```